# How to filter and select the object of selected item in ES6

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

For example I have this array structure:

```
const sampleData = [
{
  group: "GroupA",
  details: [
    {
      id: 123,
      name: "Mike",
      category: "Basketball"
    },
    {
      id: 456,
      name: "John",
      category: "Golf"
    },]
  },
  {
   group: "GroupB",
  details: [
    {
      id: 890,
      name: "Jenny",
      category: "Gymnastic"
    },
    {
      id: 45611,
      name: "Santis",
      category: "Chess"
    },]
  },
]
```

and I have this select function that will return the `details.id`

For example I selected `Mike` then it will return `123` and I want to have this value instead (Note the only returned value is the `id`)

```
 {group: GroupA, id: 123, name: "Mike", category: "Basketball"}
```

Right now I'm using this:

```
  const temp = sampleData?.findIndex(({ details }) =>
      details.findIndex(({ id }) => id === e) // e has the `id` value
    );
 console.log(temp);
```

but it seems that it's the wrong approach.

Is there a solution in ES6 or even lodash for this scenario?

Comment: You sample `array` is not valid data. you need to fix that first please so that an appropriate answer can be provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't particularly efficient, but unless you're searching through millions of records I don't think the performance is going to be a concern:

```js
const sampleData = [{
    "group": "GroupA",
    "details": [{
        "id": 123,
        "name": "Mike",
        "category": "Basketball"
      },
      {
        "id": 456,
        "name": "John",
        "category": "Golf"
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "group": "GroupB",
    "details": [{
        "id": 890,
        "name": "Jenny",
        "category": "Gymnastic"
      },
      {
        "id": 45611,
        "name": "Santis",
        "category": "Chess"
      },
    ]
  },
]

const findGroup = name => sampleData.find(group => group.details.some(entry => entry.name === name));
const findItem = name => {
  const group = findGroup(name);
  const item = group?.details?.find(({name: n}) => n === name);
  return item ? { group: group.group, ...item } : null;
}

console.log(findItem('Jenny'));
console.log(findItem('Mike'));
```

Comment: sampleData is also an array... what i want is to have this value {group: GroupA, id: 123, name: "Mike", category: "Basketball"}

Comment: Your sample data structure is broken. Sec.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only `forEach` and normal for loop instead of using `find`

```js
const sampleData = [{
    "group": "GroupA",
    "details": [{
        "id": 123,
        "name": 'Mike',
        "category": "Basketball"
      },
      {
        "id": 456,
        "name": 'John',
        "category": "Golf"
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "group": "GroupB",
    "details": [{
        "id": 890,
        "name": 'Jenny',
        "category": "Gymnastic"
      },
      {
        "id": 45611,
        "name": 'Santis',
        "category": "Chess"
      },
    ]
  }
]


function findId(nam) {
  let user = {};
  sampleData.forEach((item) => {
    for (let x = 0; x < item.details.length; x++) {
      if (item.details[x].name === nam) {
        user = item.details[x]
      }
    }
  })
  return user;
}

console.log(findId('Mike'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using find() in a simple for-of loop

```js
const idByName = (nm) => {
   let id;   
   for( group of sampleData){        
        id =  group.details.find(({name}) => name === nm )?.id || false;
        if(id)  break;      
    }  
    return id;
}
    
console.log(idByName('Mike'))
```

```html
<script>
  const sampleData = [
  {
    "group": "GroupA",
    "details": [
      {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "Mike",
        "category": "Basketball"
      },
      {
        "id": 456,
        "name": "John",
        "category": "Golf"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "group": "GroupB",
    "details": [
      {
        "id": 890,
        "name": "Jenny",
        "category": "Gymnastic"
      },
      {
        "id": 45611,
        "name": "Santis",
        "category": "Chess"
      }
    ]
  }
]
</script>
```